# Making Immobile carnivore

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

I recently finished watching one of the Star Wars films, the one that features the sarlaac pit. When I saw it, I began to immediately think how such a thing would evolve.

The sarlaac pit is essentially a carnivorous living pit that firsts begins its life as what we could define as spores, in which will burrow themselves deep in the earth and never move from that spot, subsiding only on the creatures that unfortunately fall into its mouth. When the unfortunate creature falls into the sarlaac pit, it’ll be injected with a neurotoxin that causes constant pain and be digested over a period of millennia.

To be clear when I ask my question, I’m not going to be asking about how the sarlaac pit could possibly evolve or exist, and I used it as just pure reference, and another great reference could be the ant lion.

**what conditions would allow for a COMPLETELY immobile carnivore to evolve**

If a completely immobile carnivore species isn’t possible, then could you explain how a carnivorous species with the least mobility evolve

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: you mean akin to venus fly trap, pitcher plant, and other carnivorous plant but using ant lion method?

Comment: Yes actually, something akin to that

Comment: `be digested over a period of millennia` that carnivorous specimen better hurry up, something like a few order of magnitude. I'm quite afraid the bacteria will get them digested in a matter of days to few tens of days.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The Sarlaac has a special section of it's stomach where it puts it's victims and artificially keeps them alive for 1,000 years to digest them, so you don't need to worry about bacteria! Yes, that makes no sense because of energy consumption. *shrugs*.

Comment: @Halfthawed right, no guts bacteria inside the victim, it injects them with UV light. :eyeroll: :starwars:

Comment: The search term you are looking for is [sessile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sessility_(motility)) animals. Lots and lots and lots of animal species are sessile.

Comment: I don't think anything would evolve to be carnivorous if it can last millenia without eating and doesn't need to move, at this point it will just be a plant or filter feeder like a sponge.

Answer (score 4):

[Sea anemones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_anemone) are what you are looking for

> Sea anemones are a group of marine, predatory animals of the order Actiniaria. They are named after the anemone, a terrestrial flowering plant, because of the colourful appearance of many. Sea anemones are classified in the phylum Cnidaria, class Anthozoa, subclass Hexacorallia. As cnidarians, sea anemones are related to corals, jellyfish, tube-dwelling anemones, and Hydra. Unlike jellyfish, sea anemones do not have a medusa stage in their life cycle.
>
> A typical sea anemone is a single polyp attached to a hard surface by its base, but some species live in soft sediment and a few float near the surface of the water.

They stay immobile and let the water flow bring nutrients to them.

Comment: So, we have the sea anemone and the desert anemone (Sarlacc) - now we just need a mountain anemone, swamp anemone and plains anemone...